# How to track a app download source at Apple App Store?

Tags: app-store

Here's the problem. We have several partner to promo our apps (at Apple App Store). But we can't know how many downloads from each partner.
Is there have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides no analytics information as to referer for any download.  If you put your own analytics in the app, you might be able to guess a referral if a customer use the same IP address for the first run of the app as for the referrer, but an estimate using this method won't be accurate for a number of reasons.